# Omit the border between two divs

Tags: html, css, position

I have two divs, and I want them to "look like" surrounded by same border. can anyone help me solving this problem?

I would like it to look like

```
 _____
|top  |
|     |__
|bottom  |
|        |
 ─────────
```

PS. the way I tried is to add `border-bottom : white` in ``#top` div.

However, it becomes more complicated because the `#bottom` div I need it style to include `position: absolute` yet the `#top` div not have `position: absolute`.

Here is the html.

```html
<div id='top'>
   top
</div>
<div id='bottom'>
   bottom
</div>
```

Here is the css

```css
#top{
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    border : solid 1px black;
    border-bottom : solid 3px white;
    position : relative;
    z-index : 1000;
}

#bottom{
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    border : solid 1px black;
    position : absolute;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle if you need

http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/T3bLq/

thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: Isn't it what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/T3bLq/1/ ?

Comment: are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/T3bLq/3/

Comment: Surprised nobody's suggested border-bottom:0; yet...

Comment: The answer from Milkmannetje is exactly the result I expected, but I would like the #bottom style not have style position : absolute

Comment: If you need to represent your ascii exactly you would have to go with tables. you can't have half a border on top of your bottom div. You could fake it however by giving your top div a bottom border color that matches the background :)  But you're still left with a 1px white hole on the left. :(

Comment: Anju Raghunath you provide a good try, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, try with before selector:

```
#top {
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    border : solid 1px black;
    border-bottom : none;
    background:#FFF;
}
#bottom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-top: none;
}
#bottom:before{
    content: "";
    display:block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sagix/vTyeS/

Comment: your answer is really interesting, and i don't know this :before selector, that's a will try!

Answer (score 2):

Just let them overlap for a bit.
Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/T3bLq/2/

```
.box {
position: relative;
}

#top{
width : 100px;
height : 100px;
border : solid 1px black;
border-bottom : solid 3px white;
position : absolute;
z-index : 1000;
}

#bottom{
top: 102px;
width : 200px;
height : 200px;
border : solid 1px black;
position : absolute;
}


<div class="box">
<div id='top'>
    top
</div>
<div id='bottom'>
    bottom
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but I need the #bottom one don't have style position :  abosolute , do you have any other idea?

Comment: Why can't it be absolute? Maybe you can explain in what context you want to use it.

Comment: because they are wrapped by other element and I need #top in the position of this element so I can't set it as absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Working from Milkmannetje's solution, you can give the bottom div a top margin of 100 pixels instead of an absolute position.
Because of margin collapsing, the top one then ends up in the same place as the bottom one, so I had to move the top one up by 100 pixels.

```css
#top{
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    border : solid 1px black;
    border-bottom : none;
    position : absolute;
    top:-100px;
    background:#FFF;
}

#bottom{
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    border : solid 1px black;
    margin-top:108px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/T3bLq/4/

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `position: absolute` at all, you can give the top one `display:relative` (because that is to only way to position it higher in the Z-index) and use `margin-top: -1px` for the bottom one.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/T3bLq/7/

Or, another approach, if you want to avoid `position` altogether, is to switch the divs around in the source. That will also make the top one be displayed on top of the bottom one, without relying on the Z-index. then give the bottom one a large top margin, and the top one a large *negative* top margin to get them back in the same place on the screen again.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/T3bLq/8/

I would not recommend this course of action though; it's confusing. Use something like this only as a last resort.

Comment: I am wondering if there are any other way that I don't have to set absolute in #top, but still thanks for your help!

Comment: Hm, yes, but you need positioning, because the top div needs to be higher in the Z-index. Otherwise it won't be on top of the bottom one. So it's possible by using relative positioning; I edited my answer to edit the new fiddle in.

Comment: Oh, I just thought of yet another approach, that doesn't even require any positioning at all, just clever use of margins. See my second edit. Not as elegant though.